# use myfakesite.com instead of localhost in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I followed this steps:

> What I did is edit this file: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
>
> I added a line:
>   127.0.0.1 myfakesite.com
>
> Then I went to the Facebook edit app page, specifically the "Web Site"
>   setting and entered  Site Url: http://myfakesite.com Domain:
>   myfakesite.com
>
> Instead of running IIS Express, I had to run full IIS and enable
>   myfakesite.com as one of the bindings. Here is how you do it: 1)
>   Launch Internet Information Services Manager 2) Navigate to the
>   "Default Web Site" 3) Right click on that node and choose "Edit
>   Bindings" 4) In the dialog that opens click Add 5) Enter
>   myfakesite.com in "Host Name" and click OK

[image]
[image]

Why do I get?
[image]

PS: I was trying to follow [this](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website%20%28With%20Javascript%20SDK%29&referringTitle=Documentation) tutorial, but I wanted to use IIS 7 not express.

Comment: try to add 192.168.1.1 myfakesite.com  (if your network is on 192.168.1.*, or else use the network ip, and not the loop back 127.0.0.1) and see if its works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After editing `hosts` file, Go to IIS manager!
in left panel go to `SITES`,right click on it, and click `Add web site`(pic below)
http://up.vatandownload.com/images/1lchjhpzufkst5uljq.png

in new window fill all fields:
http://up.vatandownload.com/images/hghvinst528tkww6svyf.png

in picture I created new website `test.hkh.com`!
site name: a name just for your web site. it can be anything
physical Path: a folder on your hard disk
IP address: can be left with default
host name: the address you enter in address bar of your browser

ok! now you have new site running!

**Edit:**If you want to add www.test.hkh.com to your server, there is no need to create new website! Just click on name of your site in  left panel, then in right panel, click on `Bindings`, in this window click `Add`
in `host name` enter: `www.test.hkh.com`!

Click on `Ok`!

Comment: the internet website opens instead of mine. what else should I add?

Comment: @Ryan did you added myfakesite.com to your hosts file?